# A proof problem in mathematical statistics

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Let $X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n}$ be independent and identically distributed random variables, with uniform distribution in $(0,1)$. Consider $Y_{1}, \ldots, Y_{n}$ the associated order statistics and define $$V_{i} = \frac{Y_{i}}{ Y_{i + 1}}, i = 1, ..., n -1 \quad \text{and} \quad V_{n} = Y_{n}$$Show that $V_{1}, \ldots, V_{n}$ are independent and $V_{i}\sim  \textbf{Beta}(i, 1), i = 1, \ldots, n$.

---

**How could you prove this result?**

---

**My approach:** We need two prove two parts,  for to prove that $V_{i}$ are independent, we need to show something like $$f_{V_{1},V_{2},\ldots,V_{n}}(v_{1},v_{2},\ldots,v_{n})=f(v_{1})f(v_{2})\cdots f(v_{n})$$
and for the second part we need to show that $V_{i}\sim \textbf{Beta}(i,1)$, so we need to show that something like $$f(v_{i})=\frac{v_{i}^{i-1}(1-v_{i})^{1-1}}{B(i,1)}$$ is PDF of beta distribution.

Also, I think that I can prove that *the joint distribution of order statistics for uniform distribution is also a uniform distribution* and maybe use that result in the solution of problem.

I think I can use fundamental transformation theorem, but I don't sure how can I approach this problem.

Comment: Which part of the transformation is bothering you?

Comment: In the transformation $V_k=\frac{Y_k}{Y_{k+1}}$  can I assume  WLOG that $Y_{n+1}=1$? and the transformation $A=[(y_1,...y_n),0<y_1,...y_n<1]$ in $[0,1]^n$.  Also, I think is inverse is actually:
$Y_k=V_kV_{k-1}...V_n$. Is it correct?

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2367818/pdf-of-ratio-r-n-x-1-x-n-of-order-statistics-of-beta-b-alpha-1-d

Comment: Yes, I need to prove the independence for $V_{1}, \ldots, V_{n}$.

Comment: You are simply changing variables from $(y_1,\ldots,y_n)\mapsto (v_1,\ldots,v_n)$. So write the $y_i$'s in terms of the $v_i$'s, i.e. the inverse solutions should be of the form $y_n=v_n,\,y_{n-1}=v_nv_{n-1},\ldots,\,y_1=v_nv_{n-1}\cdots v_1$. The jacobian matrix is triangular, so its determinant is straightforward. Everything else falls into place once you consider that $0<y_1<\dots<y_n<1\implies 0<v_1,\ldots,v_n<1$.

Answer (score 2):

I have a very unrigourous, but simple answer: To show pairwise independence, it should be sufficient to show that knowing the ratio $Y_i/Y_{i+1}\leq x_i$ for some $i=1,\dots,n+1$ and $x_i\in(0,1)$ (here we let $Y_{n+1}\equiv 1$ for simplicity) does not tell you whether the ratio $Y_l/Y_{l+1}\leq x_l$ for some other $l\neq i,l=1,\dots,n+1$ and $x_l\in(0,1)$.

First of all, we can rewrite both equations to $Y_l\leq x_l Y_{l+1}$ and $Y_i\leq x_i Y_{i+1}$ since both RVs are positive with probability one. Now if $i<l$, the only thing this tells us is that there is some lower bound for $Y_l$. If $i>l$, we have an upper bound for $Y_{l+1}$. Either way the information is useless. This implies pairwise independence. The same goes if we have several of these equations, so we even have independence.

EDIT: I'm pretty sure the argument above does not work at all. I just let it there in the case that it helps someone find an argument that works.

Once you have independence, the rest follows easily from $\textbf{P}(Y_n\leq x_n)=x_n^n$ and $\textbf{P}(Y_{i}\leq x_i Y_{i+1})=\textbf{E}[\textbf{P}(Y_i\leq x_i Y_{i+1}|Y_{i+1})]=\textbf{E}[F_{Y_i}(x_iY_{i+1})]$ (the last equality follows from independence) where $F_{Y_i}$ is the CDF of $Y_i$.

Disclaimer: I'm really unsure about this solution, but it makes a lot of sense to me. It would be great if someone could double check.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the idea: You can condition on the ordering of the random variables! Due to symmetry and the fact that $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are continuous iid. RVs, it follows that $$\textbf{P}(X_1\leq X_2\leq\dots\leq X_n)=\frac{1}{n!}.$$ Therefore for any $(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in (0,1)^n$ it follows that \begin{align*}\textbf{P}(V_1\leq x_1,\dots,V_n\leq x_n)&=\textbf{P}(Y_1\leq x_1Y_2,Y_2\leq x_2Y_3,\dots,Y_n\leq x_n)\\&=n!\textbf{P}(Y_1\leq x_1 Y_2,\dots,Y_n\leq x_n|X_1\leq\dots\leq X_n)\textbf{P}(X_1\leq\dots\leq X_n)\\&=n!\textbf{P}(X_1\leq x_1 X_2,\dots,X_n\leq x_n|X_1\leq\dots\leq X_n)\textbf{P}(X_1\leq\dots\leq X_n)\\&=n!\textbf{P}(X_1\leq x_1 X_2,\dots,X_n\leq x_n)\\&=n!\frac{1}{n!}x_1x_2^2\cdots x_n^n.\end{align*}

In the first equality we have used the fact that $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are positive with probability 1. The second follows from symmetry and the law of total probability. The third uses the fact that $Y_i=X_i$ for this specific ordering and the fourth is really interesting: Since $X_1\leq x_1X_2$ is known, $X_1\leq X_2$ is redundant information! The same follows for the rest. Thus, you have to do some integration to get to the final result, which is exactly the formula you were looking for, since $F_{Y_i}(x)=\int^x_0 \frac{t^{i-1}}{1/i}\;dt=x^i$ for any $1\leq i\leq n$. You can get the marginal CDFs with the same trick. Hope this helped!